# How can i save multiple records in 1 key value pair?

Tags: angular, typescript

This is how i am saving 1 record

`save.ts`

```
save(){

        this.sectionObj = { 
                           "name" : this.myname,
                           "contactno"    : this.contactno
                         };
        localStorage.setItem("resume",JSON.stringify(this.sectionObj));
      }
```

Local storage is result is as below

`key` is resume

`value`  is

```
{
"name":"saurabh..",
"contactno":"892732224"
}
```

> Now i want to add another record in this key value, how do i do that so that on saving everytime it appends a new record and not just updates the current one ?

Comment: You need to load it, parse it, edit it and save it back.
Load it using JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('resume'))

Comment: ok i am getting you, please help as how do i parse it and add `this.sectionObj` to it,  saving should be similar i believe

Comment: Make an array and push all the values and store it in the local storage

Answer (score 1):

```
add(key: string, value: string) {
    // Read currently saved object
    const tmp = localstorage.getItem('resume');
    this.sectionObj = JSON.parse(tmp);

    // Add new key/value pair
    this.sectionObj[key] = value;

    // Save again
    localStorage.setItem('resume', JSON.stringify(this.sectionObj));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code to read, write and handle exception, I hope it help full to you**

```
setData(){
let tmpdata = localstorage.getItem('resume');
 this.sectionObj = {  name : this.myname, contactno : this.contactno };  
 if (tmpdata){
    this.tmpSectionObj = JSON.parse(tmpdata);
    this.tmpSectionObj.push(this.sectionObj);
    localstorage.setItem('resume',JSON.stringify(this.tmpSectionObj));

  }else{

    localstorage.setItem('resume', JSON.stringify([]));
  }
}
```

Comment: please note  sectionObj = {}; is not an array but dataObj = []; is , what should i do ?

Comment: Use some other variable to get the array of object from local storage , and get specific object by array index value and assign in this.sectiinObj

Answer (score 0):

You can use this basic concept - 
1. Get existing item in local storage
2. Parse it if exists
3. Push new object
4. Update local storage

Logic-

```
save(){
    dataObj = [];
    this.sectionObj = { "name"    : this.myname,
                           "contactno"    : this.contactno
                         };

    data    =   localStorage.getItem('resume'); //get existing item in localstorage
    if(data) //check if it exists or not empty
    {       
        dataObj =   JSON.parse(data); //parse string
    }
    dataObj.push(this.sectionObj);
    localStorage.setItem("resume",JSON.stringify(dataObj));
}
```

Comment: using your suggested code like this - `  this.data    =   localStorage.getItem('resume'); //get existing item in localstorage
                     if(this.data) //check if it exists or not empty
                     {       
                         this.dataObj =   JSON.parse(this.data); //parse string
                     }
                     this.dataObj.push(this.sectionObj);


    
    localStorage.setItem("resume",JSON.stringify(this.dataObj));` , its saying Runtime Error
this.dataObj.push is not a function

Comment: please note  sectionObj = {}; is not an array but dataObj = []; is , what should i do ?

Comment: you can always push an object into an array. So, if your localstorage does not have item 'resume' then you have to create an empty array first, then add an object to it and then save in localstorage. On next call you have an array with one object in localstorage. Now you can push your new object into existing array and then save. Hope this clarifies!